# Validation: creating sequences given certain subsequences (one going to infinity and zero simultaneously)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I have problem with few exercises.

1. I want to find a sequence that can create sequence that has **different** terms and has three subsequences: one going to minus inifnity, one to inifnity and other to zero.
   I was thinking to create 3 sequences $ a_i $, $ b_i $, $ c_i $, such as:
   $ a_i = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5....}$
   $ b_i = {1/n} $
   $ c_i = -1, -2, -3, -4 $
   Then connect it depending on i, but not sure how to create a proper sequence from those? Could it be something along for i mod 3, every 1,2,3 pick $ a_i $, $ b_i $,$ c_i $ ?
2. There are two sequences,
   $ a_i = -11, -12, -13, -14, -15, -16, -17, -18, -19....$
   $ b_i = 1000, 10001, -16, -17, -18, -19...$
   And the sequence $ b_i $ from 3rd term would then become the same as $ a_i $ from 6th term, for the rest of the sequences. Is that equivalence relation? $ a_{i-3} = b_i $ and $ b_{i-3} = a_i$ for $ i>3$ so it is symmetric. The terms are the same so it is reflexive if I understand it correctly. Then it is not transitive.

Also, what would be the correct definition of such sequences and mathematical notations for them? I am doing Real Analysis as a part of electives for my comp sci degree and am really struggling with the semantics and mathematical language for those..

Appreciate ANY help and suggestions!!

Comment: You should only ask one question per post, see [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). For #1, your idea works, but you can define the sequence using cases, such as:$$a_i = \begin{cases} i, & \text{ if } i \equiv 0 \pmod{3} \\ \frac{1}{i}, & \text{ if } i \equiv 1 \pmod{3} \\ -i, & \text{ if } i \equiv 2 \pmod{3} \end{cases}$$

Comment: For #2, it's not clear to me exactly what the proposed possible equivalence relation is - is it "the sequence $a_n$ is equivalent to the sequence $b_n$ if and only if $b_i = a_{i+3}$ for $i \ge 3$"? Or is it that the two sequences have the same "tails" starting at some index?

Comment: @Joe thank you, sorry for messing up the question, I spent some time here looking for an answer but apart from that I am fairly new here. For #2, I believe it is former.

Comment: If it's the former, can you explain how $a_n$ is equivalent to itself?